# How can I use unzip in linux to extract only dir2 from zipfile.zip/dir1/dir2?

Tags: linux, unix, unzip

I have zip file with 1 directory that stored another directory and the second hold some files. How can I unzip in one command in order to get dir 2 along with it's files.

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Did you try typing `man unzip`?

```
unzip zipfile.zip dir1/dir2
```

If you want to ignore the zip's directory structure, use the `-j (Junk paths)` option:

```
unzip -j zipfile.zip dir1/dir2 -d dir2
```

This will store all files recursively found under `dir1/dir2` into `dir2` under the current folder.

Comment: but that would unzip me both directories, I only want dir2.

Comment: See update. To my knowledge `unzip` cannot keep the directory structure, and move it, in one go, you'd have to resort to `unzip zipfile.zip dir1/dir2 && mv dir1/dir2 . && rm -r dir1`.